# Suppose $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} g(z) = B \neq0$. Prove that There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|g(z)|> 1/2|B|$ for $0 < |z-z_0|< \delta$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} g(z) = B \neq0$. Prove that There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|g(z)|> 1/2|B|$ for $0 < |z-z_0|< \delta$

I wanted to know if my proof is correct.

$|g(z)| > 1/2|B|$ (triangle inequality)

$|g(z)| > 1/2|B| \geq |g(z) - 1/2B| > 0  $ (Greater than Zero from the inital statement)

$ |g(z) - 1/2B|< \varepsilon ; if |z - z_0| < \delta $

$ |g(z) -1/2B| = |1/2z - 1/2z_0|= |1/2||z-z_0|< \varepsilon  $

$ |z - z_0| < \varepsilon/|1/2| $

Hence $0 < \delta< \varepsilon/|1/2| $

I want to know does this solve the proof.

If not I was advised by me teacher about the Estimation Lemma but Im unsure where to start.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is not a proof, but an outline of ideas that might lead to a proof. Here's how you can write an actual proof.

Let $\epsilon = \frac{|B|}{2}$. Then $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\lim_{z\to z_0} g(z) = B$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $z$, $0 < |z - z_0| < \delta$ implies $|g(z) - B| < \epsilon$. By the triangle inequality, if $0 < |z - z_0| < \delta$, then $$|g(z)| \ge |B| - |g(z) - B| > |B| - \epsilon = \frac{|B|}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I will try and look into that. What you have suggest makes sense. I do not need the estimation lemma at any time do I?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the estimation lemma, but all you needed for this problem is a choice of $\epsilon$ in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of $\lim_{z\to z_0} g(z) = B$ to get $|g(z)| > (1/2)|B|$ for $0 < |z - z_0| < \delta$. Makes sense?

Comment: Sorry I only mention it because my teacher says it may have to do with it. I defo get what you are saying, Now looking over answer afew times I think i get it. Thanks

Comment: Kobe, I get everything but one bit. |g(z)|≥|B|−|g(z)−B|. Should it not be |g(z)|≥|g(z)−B|-|B|. I may be wrong but I do not understand this step.

Comment: We have $$|B| = |B - g(z) + g(z)| \le |B - g(z)| + |g(z)| = |g(z) - B| + |g(z)|,$$ hence $|g(z)| \ge |B| - |g(z) - B|$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That clears up all my problems with this topic.